# Apache Spark Query only on YEAR from "dd/mm/yyyy" format

Tags: python, mysql, apache-spark, bigdata

I have more than 1 Million records in excel file. I want to query on the Table using python, but date format is `dd/mm/yyyy`. I know that in MySQL the supported format is `yyyy-mm-dd`. I am restricted towards changing the format of date. Is there any possibility that I could do it on run-time. Just query on `yyyy` from `dd/mm/yyyy` and fetch the record.

[image: This this the format of date in my Excel File]

How Do I query on such format only on `Year` and not on Month or Date to get data ?

Comment: im not quite sure what you are asking, but i think you are looking for [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: `'select * from TABLE where year(date) = 2016'` ? the page i link gives you all sorts of ways of messing with dates

Comment: @Nullman I have already tried that. It does not work on `dd/mm/yyyy` format. I assume it needs `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

Comment: ohh i see. did you try using substring() and concat() change the format?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the "date" is being received as a string, then `RIGHT(date, 4)` will give you just the year.

(I see no need to reformat the string if you only need the data.  Otherwise see [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)